# Tool to test SSL performance

Tags: linux, software-testing, ssl

I'm trying to implement a TLS server with a custom engine (my server has a hardware accelerator). I want to test the performance of my server w/ wo the engine such as number of handshake per second, number of connection ….

I found a lot of online website to test SSL server but couldn't find anything to do that locally (since I can't bring the server online yet).

Is there any tools/ software to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

`openssl` has a `s_time` subcommand whose manual states:

> openssl-s_time, s_time - SSL/TLS performance timing program
>
> The s_time command implements a generic SSL/TLS client which connects to a remote host using SSL/TLS. It can request a page from the server and includes the time to transfer the payload data in its timing measurements. It measures the number of connections within a given timeframe, the amount of data transferred (if any), and
>          calculates the average time spent for one connection.

And you have various switches to control the TLS negotiation.

Also, but probably more complicated, if your piece of code can fit in `openssl` framework and appear there as an  *engine* then `openssl speed` could test it.